# pandas 1.0 replace one string dtype columns with NANs

Tags: pandas

I've started using StringDtype in pandas 1.0.1  I know it's considered experimental, but I'm running into an issue when using replace on a column of type string that contains NaNs.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', None]}, dtype='string')
df.replace({'c': 'e'})
```

The above results in:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'str'
```

Is this potentially a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', None]}, dtype='string')

df.replace('c', 'e', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

you'll get:

```
      a
0     a
1     b
2     e
3  <NA>
```

or if you want to keep the `dict` as to_replace value, you'll need first:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', np.nan]
s = pd.Series(list)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': s})    

df.replace({'c': 'e'}, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

with the output:

```
     a
0    a
1    b
2    e
3  NaN
```

couldn't really explain why it works, even though have read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).